# Prove: $<S>$ $= G$, and every $x \in G$ can be written as $x = s_{1}s_{2}$ with $s_{1}, s_{2} \in S$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-writing

I'm trying to solve this problem for my math study, but the things I'm trying don't seem to work.

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $S \subset G$ a subset of $G$, with #$S > 1/2 $#$G$

Prove:
a) $\langle S \rangle$ (the generated set of $S)$ $= G$
b) $\forall$ $x \in G: x = s_{1}s_{2}$ with $s_{1}, s_{2} \in S$

For a), I've come so far:
Assume #$S > 1/2$ #$G$
$\Rightarrow order(S) > 1/2$ $order(G)$
$\Rightarrow 2$ $order(S) > order(G)$
$\Rightarrow 2$ $order(\langle S \rangle) > order(G)$

And I also did this:
Assume $\langle S \rangle$ $\neq G$
$\Rightarrow $ $\exists$ $g \in G: g \notin \langle S \rangle$

Thats all I know for a). For b), I have really no idea on how to do it. Could you please explain me the two proofs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Some hints.

For the first part - remember that $\left<S\right>$ is a subgroup of $G$ - in fact, it's the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $S$.  You know that it has order more than $1/2$ that of $G$.  What's a famous theorem linking orders of subgroups with the order of the whole group?

For the second part - given an element $g$ of your group, try multiplying it by $s^{-1}$ for each $s\in S$.  If you can show that for some $s_2$ you get that $s_2^{-1}g\in S$, then we can write $s_2^{-1}g=s_1$, so $g=s_1s_2$.  Why are we guaranteed to land in $S$ eventually?

Further hint: if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a set $C$, and $\#A,\#B>1/2\#C$, what can you say about $A$ and $B$?

This second part actually implies the first part.

If you don't mind me asking, how much experience have you with group theory, and why are you doing these questions?

Comment: I am in the first year of my math study and have followed the course group-theory for about half a year now. So I'm not quite a specialist, but I think I know most of the basic theories. In your hint you said that the order of S is 1/2 that of G, but it is greater than 1/2 that of G. Does that change anything? For the rest, thank you for the hints! I will try something, and let you know if I'm still not getting it

Comment: @Peter That was a mistake on my part; I'll correct it.

Comment: OK. But can you see in the way I'm writing that I'm not a specialist? any corrections are welcome :-)

Comment: @ Donkey_2009 I completely understand the first part now. For the second part, I know that when I take $g \in G, s_{1} \in S \Rightarrow s_{1}^{-1}g \in <S>$. But how follows then that $s_{1}^{-1}g \in S$?

Comment: @Peter It's nothing about your writing - it's just that the working you've provided doesn't go beyond the most basic algebraic manipulations, which mad me think you hadn't much experience in group theory.  That might well have been a miscalculation on my part.

Comment: For the second part of this, it is definitely not true that $s_1^{-1}g\in S$ for all $s_1\in S$.  You only need to show that it is true for a particular value of $s_1$.  How can you use the fact that $\#(S)>(1/2)\#(G)$ here?

Comment: @ Donkey_2009 Is this true: because the order of S is more than 1/2 that of G, and G = <S>, every element in G is a product of powers of $s_{i} \in S$, and therefore there are $s_{i}$ in S with their inverse also in s. I only don't see why this has to mean that for every g in G, there is an $s_{i} \in S$ for which $s_{i}^{-1}g \in S$. Sorry for my slow understanding, but can you explain that to me?

Comment: @Peter I've added a further hint to my answer.

Comment: @ Donkey_2009 There are elements that are in $A \cap B$? So there are elements that are in $S \cap \langle S\rangle$. $g \in \langle S\rangle$, but how does it follow that $s_{i}^{-1}g \in S$ for some g?

Comment: @Peter Remember that $\left<S\right>=G$.  So $S\cap\left<S\right>$ is just $S$.  So that's not telling you much.  Can you think of another possibility for the set $B$?

Comment: @ Donkey_2009 It has at least 1 element? the order of B is bigger than 1/2 times the order of C? #B is not a divisor of #C, unless they are equal? I can't imagine what else you would mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22065/discussion-between-donkey-2009-and-peter).

Comment: Is it the subset {$gs^{-1} | s \in S$}?

Comment: @Peter Very well done!  Shall we talk about it in chat again?

Comment: yes! finally! that's ok